# How to deploy express react app to aws elastic bean stalk?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I currently am trying to deploy an app to aws as an elastic beanstalk instance with a react frontend and express backend.

this is the current file structure, and the client folder is the create react app

[image]

I ran the npm run build script that comes with the create-react-app, but the `eb deploy` deployment failed.

Am i suppose to do `eb init` in the react "client" folder or run it in the express main repo portion? Is there suppose to be a build on both the express and react portion or is there a script/npm package that builds the express api and react portion together?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you get failure after deploy which does npm start after npm install..

Add a prestart script in package.json and ebs will run the "npm run build" after "npm install" and before your npm start cmd eg: npm app.js or npm start

```
"prestart": "npm run build",
```

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your project two different ways.

First way is only using command line

```
//this command will create new t2.small instance
eb create yourappname --instance_type t2.small

//than for deploy your project
eb deploy
```

Second way you can

1. Sign in to aws console
2. Go elasticbeanstalk section
3. Create new applicaton

Then, go to your project directory on your computer,

```
//Select the instance you already created with using
eb init
//than for uplading your project or any changes you just need to use
eb deploy
```

please make sure your writing this commands inside your project directory. You can double check by using

```
pwd
```